# Example Contract for DSP Consultant

Tags: signal-analysis

I'm an Electrical Engineer working as an independent consultant on applied research type DSP projects at small startups. Can anyone please recommend a good example contract to use with my clients? Are there any good templates out there which balance the rights and responsibilities of both parties?

Comment: My suggestion is to hire a lawyer to write you a solid template.

Comment: @MBaz -- presumably these kinds of contracts are fairly boiler-plate.  Do you have a sense of how much work I should expect a lawyer to have to do?

Comment: No first hand experience, sorry, but from what I've heard i'd assume 10 to 20 hours. The benefit would be having confidence that the contract has no loopholes and that you'd be aware of all possible liabilities.

Comment: there are some bolierplate contracts.  i might make use of a boilerplate NDA, but i usually just sign the NDA the client wants me to.  somewhere i have a very flat NDA that can be used in 3-party (or more) interrogatory arrangements.  as far as the work contract, usually whoever is paying gets to write it and the contractor gets to decide if it's acceptable to him/her or if changes need to be made.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yes.  So far, it's been my experience that the client provides a contract.  I didn't know that was more or less expected.

Comment: The side that authors the contract is generally the side that has more power and is usually the side that is paying for the work.  But there are some consultants/contractors that are in such demand (they might be wizards) that when the client comes to them, the consultant tells the client what his/her terms are and the client has to decide to accept them or not.

Comment: *My* suggestion is to start with a template, and have it vetted by a lawyer.  Either way, you don't want to be your own lawyer any more than you want some lawyer to be their own DSP expert.  This is a good starting point if you're in the US, and maybe even a Commonwealth country; contractual provisions vary by country and even state, so **get a lawyer**: https://ieeeusa.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ConsultingAgreement.pdf